# How can I reverse multirow python list

Tags: python

How can I reverse the lists of a matrix in python.

EG I have:

```
example= [1,2,3],
         [4,5,6],
         [7,8,9]
```

I want to reverse each row to get the following:

```
example_reversed = [3,2,1],
                   [6,5,4],
                   [9,8,7]
```

thanks!

Comment: Is this supposed to happen in place? Also are they numpy arrays or what are the stored in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and reverse indexing :

```
>>> a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> [i[::-1] for i in a]
[[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7]]
```

Comment: With the use of map, you can eliminate the list comprehensions altogether.

Comment: Hey @Kasra you were so helpful. Can you see if you can answer my edited question? thanks!

Comment: @renegade what kind of edit you applied on question?

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix currently seems to be stored in a tuple, isn't it?

Anyway, try something like:

```
list(list(reversed(i)) for i in example)
```

But you should consider using Numpy if you need to do many computations with matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Map the `reversed` function to each item:

```
newList = map(list, map(reversed, example))
```

Comment: Does it really work with Python2? With Python3 I think that the whole expression should be encapsulated in a `list(...)`.

Comment: I'm using Python 2, so yes. Reverse returns an iterator, which you can cast to a list or keep as is. Try it for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
[list(reversed(L)) for L in example]
```

EDIT: Ugh. Way too slow, apparently.